# PL/SQL Trigger Total Value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have next 3 tables:

**player**(pid, name, value),

**team**(tid, tname, totalvalue),

**contract**(pid,tid,salary)

I want to make a trigger, which update after each insertion team.totalvalue column value. So, I want to calculate with a trigger team lot value but I fail to make it work. Who can help me? :).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER totalValue
AFTER UPDATE player 
    ON team, player,contract
        FOR EACH ROW 
            BEGIN
                SET team.totalvalue=team.totalvalue+player.value
                WHERE contract.pid=player.pid AND contract.tid=team.tid
            END;
            /
```

Comment: Is `totalvalue` the sum of all players' `value`s on a particular team? By the way, a given trigger can't exist on more than one table. Also I think you want the trigger to work on `INSERT` (new player), `UPDATE` (new value), and `DELETE` (player going to another team or retiring).

Comment: Yes, totalvalue= sum of all players value on each team.

Comment: please see my answer below. I hope it is of some assistance to you.

Comment: Why a trigger?  Would a function based index work here?  Anytime values change on the columns which the function based index is calculated, those records would be updated.... https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS00505

Comment: The difficulty with a function-based index is that it seems that an aggregate function is required.

Comment: Is this homework where a trigger is required and/or aggregate functions are prohibited? Otherwise, it just doesn't make sense...the worst way possible for maintaining running totals is with triggers. TotalValue should not even be a field of the Team table, but a field in a (materialized) view which calculates the value. That (or a UDF) is the only way to guarantee correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a trigger that I think will work for the `UPDATE` condition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER total_value
  AFTER UPDATE OF value ON player
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE team t
       SET t.totalvalue = t.totalvalue - :old.value + :new.value
     WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM contract c
                     WHERE t.tid = c.tid
                       AND c.pid = :new.pid );
END;
/
```

(I'm afraid I'm not sure off the top of my head whether a colon `:` is needed before `old` and `new`.)

In the above trigger we're subtracting the old `value` of the player and adding the new one. In the case of a `DELETE`, we would simply subtract the old `value`; for an `INSERT` we would add the new. It could probably all be done in one trigger if need be.

Comment: Yes, you would need to use `:old` and `:new` to get the values from the record being modified.  This is a good illustration of how to use a trigger to accomplish the goal, but I feel it should be pointed out that overall it's bad design to do this at all. The total can easily become incorrect if multiple sessions make changes in parallel, since they won't see each other's results. My first preference would be to simply calculate the sum on the fly when needed - possibly encapsulated in a view. If this performs badly, then a materialized view would be a better way to maintain the total.

Comment: I agree that it is not an especially good design. And a materialized view (snapshot) seems like an excellent alternative.